# Apache xml-rpc client and server implementation

Tags: java, apache, xml-rpc

I have been trying to figure out how to implement a simple xml rpc server and client with apache xml-rpc (http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) but i haven't been successfull. I implemented a server and a client as specified here in the section Webserver: http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html

The only thing i did differently was this "phm.addHandler("Calculator",org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.Calculator.class);" instead of this "phm.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), "MyHandlers.properties");". When i start the server it start properly but I can't see the service when running netstat. Then when I run a request from the client it fails because it cannot find the class to call (i.e. the client doesn't really connect to the server). I have also observed that the client can start (not sending any requests) without any errors even when the server is not running.

Anyone have any ideas. I'm really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to run both client and server on the same computer? ...that may be the reason for netstat not working. (It cannot sniff packets on the loopback address.)

If you're still interested I can post a working example.